# Should a C/C++-developer be aware of the protocols IGMP and BGP to use multicast?

Tags: c++, c, udp, multicast, multicastsocket

Do I need to know about the protocols [IGMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Group_Management_Protocol) and [BGP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Border_Gateway_Protocol) (one of [PIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Independent_Multicast)) when I write C/C++-code for **multicast**, or IGMP/BGP works fully automatically and transparently to me?

And is properly that for different IP-addresses of multicast groups different protocols build routes?

- IGMP: 224.0.0.0 - 224.0.0.255
- BGP: 224.0.1.0 - 238.255.255.255

And whad do I need to know about IGMP/BGP for using UDP-multicast?

Comment: At least for IGMP you need to take care about sending the join request, and another when you leave the multicast group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as IGMP goes, it's not something you need to worry about explicitly.

When you call `setsockopt` with either `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` or `IP_DROP_MEMBERSHIP` (or `MCAST_JOIN_GROUP` or `MCAST_LEAVE_GROUP`, among others), the OS will automatically send out the appropriate IGMP messages in addition to setting the specified interface to accept / not accept packets from the given multicast group.